# Increasing column value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 143999 rows which contains position and time data.
I already made a column "dt" which calulates the time difference between rows.
Now I want to create a new column which gives the dt values a group number.
So it starts with group = 0 and when dt > 60 the group number should increase by 1.
I tried the following:

```
def group(x):
    c = 0 #

    if densdata["dt"] < 60:
        densdata["group"] = c

    elif densdata["dt"] >= 60:
        c += 1
        densdata["group"] = c

densdata["group"] = densdata.apply(group, axis=1)'
```

The error that I get is: `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous`.

Any ideas how to fix this problem?

This is what I want:

```
   dt       group
   0.01       0
   2          0
   0.05       0    
   300        1
   2          1
   60         2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `True` evaluates to 1 and use `.cumsum()`.

```
densdata = pd.DataFrame({'dt': np.random.randint(low=50,high=70,size=20),
                         'group' : np.zeros(20, dtype=np.int32)})

print(densdata.head())
   dt  group
0  52      0
1  59      0
2  69      0
3  55      0
4  63      0

densdata['group'] = (densdata.dt >= 60).cumsum()

print(densdata.head())
   dt  group
0  52      0
1  59      0
2  69      1
3  55      1
4  63      2
```

If you want to guarantee that the first value of `group` will be 0, even if the first value of `dt` is >= 60, then use

```
densdata['group'] = (densdata.dt.replace(densdata.dt[0],np.nan) >= 60).cumsum()
```